# Javascript Quotes Problem When Dynamically Adding Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically add content stored in a variable.  However, single quotes are causing problems.

```
var dynamicelementcode = $("<div id='container'>" + data +  "</div>");
            dynamicelementcode.prependTo($('#wholecontainer')).hide().fadeIn(300).slideDown(1000);
```

If the data variable contains a single quote, it breaks my code.  How can I solve this problem?  The data variable gets its content from a serverside php script.

Any php/js/jquery solution appreciated

**Edit:**

**PHP Code Serverside**

```
$comment_body = "The boy's bicycle";

echo '{ "author": "'.$author.'", "message": "'.$comment_body.'","parentid": "'.$parent_id.'","currentid": "'.mysql_insert_id().'","timestored": "'.$timestampa.'" }';
```

**Jquery Code, Clientside**

```
var newrootcomment = $("<div class='comment'><div class='comment-holder'><div class='comment-body'>"+ data.message + "</div> <abbr class='timestamp' title=''>" + data.timestored + "</abbr><div class='aut'>" + data.author + "</div> <a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='id"+ data.currentid + "'>Reply</a> </div> </div>");
            newrootcomment.prependTo($('#wholecontainer')).hide().fadeIn(300).slideDown(1000);
```

Comment: the question is how is data exactly set. Is it substituted or is it set in JavaScript with a value defined by PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dynamicelementcode = $('<div id="container">').text(data)
```

[jQuery text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/) automatically escapes quotes for you.

---

**UPD.** Escaping only single quotes:

```
var dynamicelementcode = $('<div id="container">').html(data.replace(/'/g,'&#039;'))
```

---

**UPD 2.** If you look at the source of your page you'll see something like `"message": 'The boy's bicycle'` - that's a syntactic error.

Here's a better way to pass PHP data to JavaScript, works with quotes too:

```
$comment_body = "The boy's bicycle";
echo json_encode(array(
  'author' => $author,
  'message' => $comment_body,
  'parentid' => $parent_id,
  'currentid' => mysql_insert_id(),
  'timestamp' => $timestamp
));
```

Comment: still not working with var dynamicelementcode = $('<div id="container">').html(data.replace(/'/g,'&#039;'))

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. Can you add a data example to your question?

Comment: code added :)  This has been driving me crazy and has made my work come to a screeching halt :(

Comment: whenever there's a quote in the $comment_body var, and it transfers to JS, it breaks my code on my page.

Comment: hey, how when it outputs the dynamically added content, it shows with a slash like this: /'  How can i make it show only '

Comment: Does it contain a slash when you do alert(data.message)?

Comment: does it for double quotes too

Comment: How are you defining your data variable in JavaScript? I wonder whether you use any templating engine which might have added an extra slash.

Comment: I'm performing data sanitization, using the following functions:$data = trim($data); 

//Linkify
$data = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a rel=\'nofollow\' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $data);

//Line Breaks Preserve
$data = strtr($data, array("\r\n" => '<br />', "\r" => '<br />', "\n" => '<br />')); 

//HTMLLAWED
$data = htmLawed($data, array('safe'=>1, 'elements'=>'b, strong, i, em, li, ol, ul,u,pre,br'));

Comment: html awed: http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php

Comment: I've disable each of the above function, none of them causes it.

Comment: I've read somewhere that after you use json encode, you should use JSON.parse in javascript.  Maybe that is what should be done?

Comment: In some cases yes, but not in this one, json_encode generates valid JavaScript code. You simply do "var data = <?= json_encode(...) ?>" in your JavaScript. This function never caused any problems to me.

Comment: i'm completely baffled by this.  Can't there be a simple expression to change /' to ' ?

Comment: Yes, string.split("/'").join("'"). Also take a look at this example and try running it, maybe it helps: http://pastie.org/1590417

Answer (score 1):

jQuery already has methods to insert text, you don't need to concatenate strings or take care yourself of escaping. Use the `.text()` method:

```
var dynamicelementcode = $('<div id="container"></div>').text(data);
```

Reference and examples: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Comment: what if there are certain html tags which need to be allowed?  Like <b>, <i>,

Comment: Well, that's a slightly different question. Core jQuery cannot read `<a>` inside a string and tell out whether it's HTML or a literal `<a>`. I presume you are asking for some sort of customizable HTML parser, which can be trivial or terribly daunting depending on how reliable it needs to be.